# Python print hyperlink in gnome-terminal

Tags: python, hyperlink, gnome-terminal

I can use this special escape sequence to print a hyperlink in bash:

```sh
echo -e '\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n'
```

Result (Link I can click on):

```sh
This is a link
```

Now I want to generate this in Python 3.10:

```py
print('\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n')
\e]8;;http://example.com\e\This is a link\e]8;;\e\

print(r'\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n')
\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n
```

As you can see, the escape sequence is not interpreted by the shell.
Other escape sequences, like the one for bold text, work:

```py
print('\033[1mYOUR_STRING\033[0m')
YOUR_STRING    # <- is actually bold
```

How can I get python to format the URL correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text to the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal)

Comment: From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786287/1765658), with some tries: `print('\x1b]8;;' + 'http://example.com' + '\x1b\\' + 'This is a link' +  '\x1b]8;;\x1b\\\n' )`

Comment: Answer published!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786287/1765658), after some tries:

```
print('\x1b]8;;' + 'http://example.com' + '\x1b\\' + 'This is a link' +  '\x1b]8;;\x1b\\\n' )
```

Then better:

```
print( '\x1b]8;;%s\x1b\\%s\x1b]8;;\x1b\\' %
       ( 'http://example.com' , 'This is a link' ) )
```